# How should my PC behave after having been affected by Geas/Quest spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

The 4 level 13 mythic PCs (including mine) are attacked by high-level casters from war zeppelins. My PC was the victim an enemy caster's [***geas/quest***](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/geas-quest/) spell. (We suspect the caster actually used the spell *limited wish* or *wish* to duplicate the effect of a *geas/quest* spell because of its long casting time.)

The enemy caster gave my PC the instructions *Kill all allies of Aura*—Aura being our patron and who was not present at the encounter. The PCs are Aura's only allies currently present.

I'm not sure how should I role-play the effects of this spell. For instance, does my PC immediately attack his allies?

I'm interested practical experience with the spell but also in the [rules-as-written](/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) as it seems my opinion and the GM's differ significantly.

Comment: *We suspect the caster actually used the spell limited wish or wish to duplicate the effect of a geas/quest spell because of its long casting time.* Another possibility is a spell-like ability. There are certain worshippers of deities that can gain geas as SLA. Besmara and Braismois are the ones that come to mind.

Comment: @ShadowKras It is a possibility but it seems to me that [Universal Monster Rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Spell-Like-Abilities-Sp-) contradict [Magic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Spell-Like-Abilities-Sp-) on this subject. In either case not what makes much difference for the answer.

Comment: It does. There are conflicting answers by the developers on that subject as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Your character must immediately carry out the instructions.

The spell is based on *lesser geas*, which says:

> The geased creature must follow the given instructions until the geas is completed, no matter how long it takes.

There's not much wiggle room there.  In particular, you can't say things like "okay but I'll do this other thing first". You have to follow the instructions immediately.

## The instructions don't require you to start a one-against-three combat.

The spell also notes:

> A clever recipient can subvert some instructions.

So you do have some ability to interpret the best way to carry out a given instruction.  For example, you might argue: "well, if I attacked the other three characters right now, I'd just lose, and that wouldn't accomplish killing any of them.  The right thing to do should be to continue fighting the enemy as though nothing had happened, and then kill them in their sleep when I'm on watch tonight."

Or even: "killing my three friends tonight wouldn't be a good way to kill *all* the allies of Aura.  I'll need to become some sort of deep-cover agent, and formulate some sort of long-term plan to betray everyone at once.  I sure hope I can find a way to do that before the one-day-per-caster-level time limit runs out and the spell goes away!"

You'll note that these developments are actually a lot worse for the party's success, and arguably are less fun for you as well.  The optimal way to play this, from the point of view of the party's victory, is to run straight at the most heavily-armored character shouting "GUYS I'M MIND CONTROLLED I NEED A DISPEL QUICK!!!".  This is probably also what your GM is expecting you to do.

## The GM has a lot of latitude in this.

Although your character can (and *should*) search for the least bad way to carry out this instruction, the GM is ultimately the arbiter of what counts as "finding a creative way to obey" and what counts as "stop splitting hairs and start making melee attacks against your allies".  If the GM tells you which interpretation of the spell you have to use, you have to use that one.

---

You've asked for practical experience.  When my PCs get mind-controlled, I usually pause the action and I tell them: "your character has to do the thing, but your character is frantically searching for ways to make this less bad.  Each turn, you can tell me what you're trying to do and why you think it should count as obeying the instructions.  If I don't agree, I'll take control of your character for that round and have you obey the instructions in a straightforward way."

I remember one time when my own character was mind-controlled and made to believe that all his allies were undead and needed to be destroyed.  I immediately answered that my character was using *turn undead* at them, which did nothing except waste my character's action.  A better move would have been to use healing magic on them, expecting that the healing magic would harm the undead.

Comment: Can you briefly elaborate on this. Does this answer mean if you were given a geas to find and retrieve X item, you can't spare even a half of a day to not working on it and... lets say, go and save some random villager from random goblins before ressuming to follow your geas on the same day?

Comment: That's correct -- you can't spare any time at all for side activities. If you want to rescue a villager from goblins, you can try to find a reason why this advances your quest (maybe the villager might be able to help you retrieve X item?), but if that doesn't work then you can't rescue the villager.

Comment: This answer is good, but would be strengthened by a reference to the general rules for compulsion spells in Pathfinder.